# how to make full screen of buttons in swift 3 programmatcally

Tags: swift, swift3

i need to make a page like the main screen on iPhone with apps but make it buttons and also when i add a new button it will add it row like on the main screen menu . how i make it programmatically so it will know where to fit the new button

Comment: I think you might need to check [UICollection​View](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) component.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is the best option

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) with a [FlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html). The Flow Layout will basically arrange all cells next to each other. If one line has no more space to fit the next element it will move the cell to the next line thereby creating a Home Screen like appearance.